# How do I pass user input ref from one component to display into another component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I need help with state management in my Chat-app.

**Description:**
I am attempting to display the username entered from the `UserModal` component to my `ChatScreen` component. I am using the `onChange` function inside `UserModal` and I am using a `switch case` statement to ensure form validation. Then setting the state with name as an array and assigning the value to the name like so:

**UserModal.js**

```
onChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        let formError = this.state.formError;
        switch (name) {
            case 'userName':
                formError.userName =
                    value.length < 3 ? 'minimum 3 characters required' : '';
                break;
            default:
        }
        this.setState({ formError, [name]: value }, () =>
            console.log(this.state)
        );
    };
```

**onSubmit function**

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (formValid(this.state)) {
            Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/authenticate').then(
                (res) => {
                    if (res.data.isSuccessful === true) {
                        alert('Your username is: ' + this.input.value);
                        this.close();
                    } else {
                        alert('Error Message: ' + res.data.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
            alert(
                'Error message: Please enter a username with a minimum of 3 characters'
            );
        }
    };
```

**Form**

```
<form action="Main.js" className="form-inside-input" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate>
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input
    className={formError.userName.length > 0 ? "error" : null}
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter username"
    name="userName"
    onChange={this.onChange}
    ref={(input) => (this.input = input)}
    noValidate
  ></input>
  {formError.userName.length > 0 && <span>{formError.userName}</span>}

  <Button
    type="submit"
    positive
    icon="checkmark"
    labelPosition="right"
    content="Let me in!"
    onClick={() => {
      this.onSearch();
    }}
  />
</form>;
```

**Goal:**
My goal is to take what the user puts in the username field in the modal and display "{userName} has joined the chat." where `userName` is replaced with the input of the user, in the ChatScreen.js component within the Semantic UI fragments. 


Github Link: https://github.com/George-Jindo/chat-app

Comment: Hi, I do not think you need ref for this case. Use some state management, or higher order state or redux store shared between components

Comment: I was thinking of using Redux as an option. Higher order state you mean adding state management inside app.js and lifting the state from there?

Comment: Correct. You use state in App pass it down to the child components. If you have simple flow with 3-5 components this would be better. More complicated state flow requires redux.

Comment: @rockTheWorld Thanks, I will start moving my state over to app.js and yeah it is a simple flow since there is only about 5 components, could have been 3 but tried making cleaner code.